# Using GPS spoofing, is it possible to tell a specific app that I'm in two locations at the same time?

Tags: android, mocking, gps, location, spoof

I have a rooted/magisk Android phone and can change the location with mock locations + fake gps app, but I would somehow like to be in two places at once. Is this possible?

Android restricts the use of mock locations, only one app is allowed.

Comment: `like to be in two places at once.` You have to split up or clone yourself.

Comment: Only one application can mock the location. But all other apps will see mocked locations. In any case, an app ask for location and it expects just one location. Additional locations are just interpreted by updated locations (so yeah, in principle you can jump here and there: hope that the app can handle it).